# VBA Shortcut keys for Mac Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, macos, powerpoint

I am developing some macros in VBA for Mac PowerPoint. I would like to add some keyboard shortcuts to some of them, but it looks like the `Application.OnKey` module is not present.

Am I missing something or it looks like this is not possible at all on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

The object model in current versions of PowerPoint for Mac is quite poor. It seems like every project I try to port to it from Windows has some object missing. Today, I found that custom Ribbon modifications can't run VBA macros in PowerPoint for Mac, though the same file works in Windows and identical mods in Word and Excel work on both Windows and Mac. So I'm not surprised that you've discovered another missing object. Please report it to Microsoft using the smiley-face icon in the upper right.

Comment: You can actually use custom Ribbons to run macros, even if it requires suboptimal security settings. Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733141/developing-a-custom-ribbon-add-in-for-powerpoint-office-365-mac/57738977#57738977)